# jquery not equal in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find **phone number** and **mobile number** from an array with jquery.

**jQuery:**

```
var data = $('#PhoneLabel').text();
var array = data.split(', ');
$.grep(array, function (item, index) {
    if (item.charAt(0) === '0' && item.charAt(1) === '9') {
        var mob = item;
        $('#UserMobMenuSMS').attr('href', 'sms:' + mob);
        $('#UserMobMenuTel').attr('href', 'tel:' + mob);
        alert('its mobile');
    } else if (item.charAt(0) !== '0' && item.charAt(1) !== '9') {
        $('#UserMobMenuSMS').addClass('disableUserMenuMob');
        $('#UserMobMenuSMS').attr('href', '#');
        alert('there is no mobile');
    } else {
        var phone = item;
        $('#UserMobMenuTel').attr('href', 'tel:' + phone);
        alert('its phone');
    }
});
```

if number start with `09` it is mobile number and else it's phone number. and there is 3 forms in html:

**first, only phone number:**

<kbd>Not Working</kbd>

```
<span id="PhoneLabel" class="GlobalTelColor">021-88915907 , 021-88915907</span>
```

**second, phone number and mobile number:**

<kbd>Working good</kbd>

```
<span id="PhoneLabel" class="GlobalTelColor">09127007008 , 021-55293301-6 , 021-55293003</span>
```

**third, only mobile number:**

<kbd>Working good</kbd>

```
<span id="PhoneLabel" class="GlobalTelColor">09195328272</span>
```

the problem is in first form, if there is no mobile number in array, I want to use phone number in `#UserMobMenuTel` and disable `#UserMobMenuSMS` with `disableUserMenuMob` class. I mean when there is no mobile number `UserMobMenuSMS` should get `disableUserMenuMob` class, but it's not working, i guess i used wrong method in this case, is there any better way and solution?.

please check out the **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6eza3q1/1/)** Demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed it a bit there. added the `disableUserMenuMob` classes as intial and then removeClass as you find a mobile. If no mobile found, do nothing.

You had 3 if else switches and I felt 2 is sufficient for what you want

https://jsfiddle.net/m6eza3q1/4/

Comment: i tried this before, but it's not working good, please un comment third form. you know, the problem is second if not working at all.

Comment: I did that, But what is the result you need there? Should the SMS be enabled since a mobile is available?

Comment: Yes, when there is a mobile number SMS should enable.

Comment: Editted my answer above.